# Why are all songs structured the same way?

Tags: theory, musical-forms

Why are all songs structured the same way?

```
verse -> chorus -> verse ... (you know the drill)
```

Why don't any musicians try to break this structure? I suspect the answer is because this structure is the "magical formula" for creating the best music. Nevertheless, I can't stop to think about all the possibilities it would create if people weren't so strict about the overall structure of the song.

*This is probably a stupid off topic question - I apologize for that*

Comment: Perhaps the producers are afraid of risking money on an untried product when  a certain form is thought to guarantee a profit.  Or maybe creativity doesn't correlate with profit.

Comment: "all songs"... no they're not. You're starting from an incorrect premise. there is nothing here to answer.

Comment: Apart from the verse and chorus, most songs also have an intro and a bridge (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_(music)) and sometimes instrumental solos. Then some songs are just one thing repeated, like "work songs" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_song) and related genres; have a listen to Hank Williams' "Ramblin' Man" (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V41gDDWEPso)

Comment: Jefferson Airplane: “White Rabbit” check it out. Just one example among countless others. There are many songs, like “Brown Eyed Girl”, that don’t have proper choruses.

Comment: And then there's "Bohemian Rhapsody" :-)

Answer (score 4):

They're not. Pull out your average Christmas carol. Chances are, it's not in verse-chorus form. Heck, it's often made of only verses (e.g. "O Come All Ye Faithful", "Silent Night", "Hark! The Herald Angels Sing", "O Holy Night").

Then, the additive, incremental structure of "The Twelve Days of Christmas" is truly a mess.

It's not like it's only Christmas carols that deny verse-chorus form, either. Tom Lehrer's ["The Elements"](https://genius.com/Tom-lehrer-the-elements-periodic-table-lyrics) also is not in verse-chorus form.

And try listening to some progressive rock songs and get back to me....

Comment: I'm not sure that *O Come, All Ye Faithful* & *Hark! The Herald* are the best examples of hymns without chorus. Don't the final couplets of the verses in these carols serve a a burden/chorus?